# ASUS Vivobook 14 Overheating Issue on Ubuntu 22.04 with Ryzen 7

Tags: shutdown, asus, cpu, overheating, temperature

I'm encountering an issue with my ASUS Vivobook 14 M1402IA-AM173 running Ubuntu, equipped with 16GB RAM and a Ryzen 7 4800Hs processor. Just to clarify, I'm using the default power management settings.Here's what's happening: Whenever I start my laptop and open applications like PHPStorm or run unit tests in PHP (I use Paratest for parallel test execution), all my CPU cores ramp up to their maximum frequency. According to htop, this goes up to 4000 MHz, and even when the processor heats up, it doesn't throttle down to prevent overheating. Eventually, this leads to a 'poweroff' command, and my Ubuntu system shuts down unexpectedly. Unfortunately, I can't monitor the CPU temperature as it seems there might not be a sensor for it.

Is it possible to somehow assess the acceptable CPU value up to 3700 MHz?